# Covariance when expected value does not exist

Tags: probability, expected-value

The question I'm solving asks for the covariance but the expected value of a variable diverges. E(XY) is known so would Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) or would the covariance also not exist because of the divergence?

Comment: If your expected value diverges, the probability distributon function is not valid. Have you checked that the distribution function you are using is a probability function, ie $\int ^{\infty }_{-\infty } f( x) dx=1$.

Comment: The Cauchy distribution has no finite moments but is a valid probability distribution.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Existence of expected value (or, generally, finite moments of any positive order) is not necessary for a probability distribution to be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The covariance is defined for random variables *with finite second moments*. If either $X$ or $Y$ in your example does not have a well-defined first moment, it doesn't have a finite second moment either, and the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is not defined.